# How to get android sdk for visual studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, android-2.2-froyo

I have just downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition to start developing Android application using C#. But no option is present there for developing android / ios apps using C#.
Can anyone suggest me how could I download and install android SDK for Visual studio 2013 community edition and start working on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx#NET